# gmail inbox contents disappeared mysteriously

Tags: gmail, inbox-by-gmail

This has happened to my wife twice on her LG Optimus G phone, once about a week ago, and again just today.  She pulls up gmail on her phone, she taps on edit, and begins typing in an email address.  She sees the address she needs in the autocomplete.  Then decides not to finish the email.  So she taps the back key on here phone to get back to the gmail inbox (the page that gmail always wakes up with) and Whoa!  Her inbox is now empty!!  Where did all the emails go.  She then pulls out her laptop and checks her gmail from there.  Inbox still empty.  Can't find the emails under all mail, trash, or spam either.  They are gone.

Has anyone else out there experienced this problem?  Any ideas?  I'm wondering if it's a bug in the new gmail app (that downloaded itself a couple of weeks ago).  Or could it be some kind of a virus?   Anyone have any ideas?  Please help.

Comment: Which Gmail app are you talking about? "Gmail", or "Inbox by Gmail"? You've tagged your question with both.

Comment: I'm not sure.  I guess regular gmail.  
App Info says "Gmail Version 5.0 (1569867)".  Thanks